# What addressing paradigms are being used for high performance computing?

Tags: parallel-processing, cluster-computing, hpc, supercomputers

What's the difference between "Active Global Address Space ( **AGAS** )" and "Partitioned Global Address Space ( **PGAS** )" used for high performance computing?

It's not a specific question about implementation, so I think this information will be sufficient.

*For example:*
(software based) AGAS is used by [HPX](https://github.com/STEllAR-GROUP/hpx) c++ runtime system
and
PGAS was used by parallel programming languages like Chapel, UPC etc.